# Question about injectivity of vector valued functions knowing that one of its component is injective

Tags: analysis, functions, solution-verification

Consider an interval $I \subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and a function $f:I\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and suppose that at least one of the components of $f$ is an injective function, that is there exist $k \in \{1,...,n\}$ such that $f_k:I\to\mathbb{R}$ is injective. Does this imply that $f$ is injective?

I believe yes, because: given $x_1,x_2$ in $I$, by definition of equality of ordered $n$-uple it is $$\left(f_1(x_1),f_2(x_1),...,f_k(x_1),...,f_n(x_1)\right)=(f_1(x_2),f_2(x_2),...,f_k(x_2),...,f_n(x_2))$$
$$\iff [(f_1(x_1)=f_1(x_2)) \wedge (f_2(x_2)=f_2(x_2)) \wedge ... \wedge(f_k(x_1)=f_k(x_2)) \wedge  ... \wedge (f_n(x_1)=f_n(x_2))]$$but the truth of a logical conjunction of $n$ propositions implies the truth of all the $n$ propositions alone, and so in particular
$$[(f_1(x_1)=f_1(x_2)) \wedge (f_2(x_2)=f_2(x_2)) \wedge ... \wedge(f_k(x_1)=f_k(x_2)) \wedge  ... \wedge (f_n(x_1)=f_n(x_2))] \implies f_k(x_1)=f_k(x_2)$$
since by hypothesis $f_k$ is injective, $f_k(x_1)=f_k(x_2) \implies x_1=x_2$ and so it is
$$[\left(f_1(x_1),f_2(x_1),...,f_k(x_1),...,f_n(x_1)\right)=(f_1(x_2),f_2(x_2),...,f_k(x_2),...,f_n(x_2))] \implies x_1=x_2$$
that is $f$ is injective. Is this proof correct?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: That's fine! Good effort on giving a lot of detail here. I think you can almost always get away with giving less detail than this. "If two $n$-tuples are equal, then their $k$-th entries are equal" usually doesn't need proof in my opinion. A closely related fact to your question is that given functions $f$, $g$ with appropriate domains and codomains, if $g \circ f$ is injective, then $f$ is injective. This is a special case of that, where $g$ is the $k$-th coordinate projection.